# Simple question about finding roots of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots, factoring

What am I doing wrong here?

This is the denominator of one of my problems and I need to find the roots, so:

$6i-z^2+1 \to z=\sqrt{1+6i}$ and $z=-\sqrt{1+6i}$

$\therefore$ $(z+\sqrt{1+6i})(z-\sqrt{1+6i})$

But when I multiply them back together, I get

$$z^2-6i-1$$

, which doesn't match the original expression. I know I'm making a very simple mistake somewhere...

Comment: You simply forgot to factor out the leading coefficient ($-1$).

Comment: Again? Same mistake as in your other question... Of course, $(z-z_1)(z-z_2)=z^2-(6i+1)$. If you want $6i+1-z^2$, consider $(z-z_1)(z_2-z)$.

Comment: @Did I know it was similar but I just didn't think I understood it correctly because I couldn't apply it here...math novice here :P

Comment: Friendly suggestion: type less, think more. Or simply: slow down...

Comment: People tell me that a lot lol....maybe I should actually do that haha!

Answer (score 0):

$$
(z+\sqrt{1+6i})(z-\sqrt{1+6i}) = z^2 - (\sqrt{1+6i})^2 = z^2 - (1 + 6i)
$$

$$
-(-z^2+(1+6i)) = -[ 6i - z^2+1]
$$